# How to use RLimitCPU

Tags: php, apache, configuration

How I can Limit cpu usage of apache2 php scirpts using

```
 RLimitCPU  seconds|max [seconds|max]
```

Please show me an example.

e.g RLimitCPU 2 2 ? whats that mean ?
I know its cpu seconds but question is how to convert GHz to seconds.
One php for video streaming script sometimes is taking 100% CPU usage on 2 cores.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#rlimitcpu

Answer (score 1):

1 GHz is 1,000,000,000 CPU cycles per second - so a 2.6 GHz CPU is going to go through 2,600,000,000 cycles in one second. How many instructions actually get executed in a cycle is going to vary with the CPU - they'll all take a certain number of cycles to actually complete an instruction.

2 CPU seconds is "the CPU is completely maxed out for two full seconds or the equivalent". So if your program uses the CPU at half capacity for 4 full seconds that's 2 CPU seconds.

For your app, if you have a 2.6 GHz CPU and you run at 2 CPU seconds, you'll have executed 5,200,000,000 CPU cycles. How many instructions that is harder to work out, and how many instructions you actually need for your "video streaming script" is going to be incredibly hard to work out (and is going to vary with the length of the video).

I'd advise just running the script for the biggest video you'd ever send, seeing how many CPU seconds you use (top -u apache-usr will let you see the PHP process running, "TIME+" column is CPU time) and then tripling that as your RLimitCPU.

Bear in mind that RLimitCPU is just going to kill your PHP script when it takes more CPU time than the limit. It's not some magical tool that means your script will take less CPU time, it's just a limit on the maximum time the script can take.

Answer (score -1):

**Apache Reference: http_core, RLimitCPU**

**RLimitCPU**

```
Resource Limit on CPU Usage

Syntax: RLimitCPU soft-seconds [hard-seconds]

Example: RLimitCPU 60 120

Since: Apache 1.2
```

This directive sets the soft and hard limits for maximum CPU usage of a process in seconds. It takes one or two parameters. The first parameter, soft-seconds, sets the soft resource limit for all processes. The second parameter, hard-seconds, sets the maximum resource limit. Either parameter can be a number, or `max'', which indicates to the server that the limit should match the maximum allowed by the operating system configuration. Raising the maximum resource limit requires the server to be running as the user`root'', or in the initial start-up phase.

http://www.apacheref.com/ref/http_core/RLimitCPU.html